# What is the most pythonic way to sort a dict with list values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary with values as a list of integers. What is the pythonic way to sort the values for each key?
In my approach I am overwriting each key value after sorting.

Is there a way to maintain the sorting on insertion into the dictionary or is it better to store first and then sort the values efficiency wise?

```py
my_dict = {
'first': [3,6,99],
'second': [1,-10,100],
'third': [5,0,23,67,29]
}

# my approach
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[key] = sorted(values)
```

**Ouput:**

```
my_dict = {
'first': [3,6,99],
'second': [-10,1,100],
'third': [0,5,23,29,67]
}
```

Comment: So you are basically asking, if there's an inplace-sort?

Comment: Instead of overwriting existing keys you can simply sort the values in-place: `for value in my_dict.values(): value.sort()`. You can't maintain sorting using built-in data structures but there are third party packages: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedlist

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with building unsorted lists first and sorting them afterwards.

Comment: I am working aon a comprehensive solution and I would aprecaite your desired output

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Your code never inserts the initial values into the dict, so it's hard to say whether sorting on insertion would be most efficient. In the case of a literal, the most efficient way is to already write the literal in the shape/ordering as desired – but that's likely not what you are asking about, is it?

Comment: @TERMINATOR updated with expected output

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, you want to sort the lists in place, so use [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

```py
my_dict = {
    'first': [3,6,99],
    'second': [1,-10,100],
    'third': [5,0,23,67,29]
}

for val in my_dict.values():
    val.sort()
```

[Live demo](https://www.online-python.com/MYspV61tP8)

Check this [sorting how to guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: @TERMINATOR you cannot do a list comprehension because it is a dict (so it would be a dict comprehension) Then, sorting in place is the most performant way of sort here, since you avoid creating intermediate data.

Comment: Your way is only marginally more performative by only `0.0003509000000000151`seconds , so here `Flat is better than nested.`(PEP20) should take priority

Comment: @TERMINATOR, what is the testing set that you used? Increase the list sizes and create a graph, you will notice things :)
Btw, that you write it in one line it doesn't mean that the comprehension is flatter. You could as well write the loop in one line if you would (for some reason) want so.

Comment: What about `Explicit is better than implicit`

Comment: What is more explicit than just sorting what you have? Just sort the values in my dict, that is all you need to do. Not create a new dictionary with a copy of the values sorted.

Comment: Note the question isn't the most efficient way but the most pythonic, and they are quite often different things

Comment: @TERMINATOR, and still you have not refuted the arguments. Anyway, I really have no time for this. Thanks for you opinion anyway :)

Comment: And thanks for yours, I guess since being pythonic isn't a clear cut definition we can both be right

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

[pythonic code](https://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html) makes use of programming patterns such as list comprehensions or generator expressions, attempt to crowbar in patterns more commonly used in C or java. Loops are particularly common examples of this.Pythonic code also makes use of inline sintaxes as mentioned by [PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)(`Beautiful is better than ugly.`, `Flat is better than nested.`)

Firstly, your code is good but to be more pythonic you should make use of sytaxes such as list comprehnsions/dict comprehensions. I will cover the most efficient way that has the least lines of code using a dict comprehension instaed of a for loop to be more pythonic even hough for loops are considered to be pyhonic list & dict comprehensions are more pythonic(they are flat syntaxes).

**Here is the code:**

```
my_dict = {
'first': [3,6,99],
'second': [1,-10,100],
'third': [5,0,23,67,29]
}

sorted_dict = {key:sorted(value) for key, value in my_dict.items()}
print(sorted_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'first': [3, 6, 99], 'second': [-10, 1, 100], 'third': [0, 5, 23, 29, 67]}
```

Comment: "to be Truely pythonic one must write as little code to get a job done" This seems like a bold claim to make.

Comment: This is not a list comprehension, nor a modified list comprehension. It is a dict comprehension. It's also not particularly efficient, creating an entirely new dict and values and throwing away the old ones.

Comment: I have been more precise in my answer and have worked on your concersn but my code does make use of more pytonic syntaxes

Comment: It does? As far as I can tell, both [``for`` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) and [``dict`` comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) are Pythonic syntax.

Comment: FWIW The dict comprehension does look sexier than a multi-line loop and [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states clearly that `Beautiful is better than ugly.` as well as `Flat is better than nested.`. The only improvement I would suggest on this method (assuming you don't care about the performance comparison between in-place sorting vs creating new, sorted lists) would be to change the variable names to make it more readable:
`sorted_dict = {key: sorted(value) for key, value in my_dict.items()}` (`Readability counts.` and `Explicit is better than implicit.`)

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension to make it into a one-liner:
`[value.sort() for value in my_dict.values()]` will in-place sort all the values in the dictionary and create a list of `None` objects as a by-product. Probably not very pythonic at all but interesting all the same

Comment: I will test the list  approach tomorrow and will ad it as an alternative if it works